# BLUEZ - is propagation delay of ~50ms normal for BLE?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez

I'm trying to sample TI CC2650STK sensor data at ~120Hz with my Raspberry Pi 3B and when comparing the signal trace to a wired MPU6050 I seem to have a ~50ms phase-shift in the resultant signal (in the image below orange is the data received over BLE and blue is the data received over I2C with another sensor (MPU6050):
[image]

The firmware on the sensor side doesn't seem to have any big buffers:

(50{ *ms* }/8{ *ms/sample* } = ~6 { *samples* }), where each sample is 18bytes long -> 6*18 buffer size req'd I guess...).

On the RPi side I use Bluez with Bluepy library and again I see no buffers that could cause such a delay. For test purposes the sensor is lying right next to my pi, so surely OTA transmission cannot be taking 40-50ms of time? More so, timing my code that handles the incoming notifications shows that the whole handling (my high level code + bluepy library + BLUEZ Stack) takes less than 1-2 *ms*.

Is it normal to see such huge propagation delay or would you say I'm missing something in my code?

Comment: Better consult in BlueZ mailing list. http://vger.kernel.org/vger-lists.html#linux-bluetooth

Comment: Thanks, will do! But generally speaking, is it normal to see a delay like this for a BLE sensor lying right next to an acquisition device?

Comment: No, not at all.

Answer (score 1):

Looks legit to me.

BLE is timeslotted. Peripheral cannot transmit any time it wants, it has to wait for next *connection event* for sending its payload. If next connection event is right after sensor data update, message gets sent with no big latency. If sensor data is generated right after connection event, peripheral stack has to wait a complete *connection interval* for next connection event.

*Connection interval* is an amount of time, multiple of 1.25 ms between 7.25 ms and 4 s, set by Master of the connection (your Pi's HCI) upon connection. It can be updated by Master arbitrarily. Slave can kindly ask for modification of parameters from the Master, but master can do whatever it wants (most Master implementation try to respect constraints from Slave though).

If you measure an average delay of 50 ms, you are probably using a *connection interval* of 100 ms (probably a little less because of constants delays in the chain).

Bluez contains a `hcitool lecup` command line that is able to change the connection parameters for a given connection.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Actually, I'm using 7.5 ms connection interval. My hcitool lecup parameters are as such:
hcitool lecup --handle %handle% --min 6 --max 7 --latency 0 --timeout 10

On the sensor side I also sample every 7.5 ms. As such, worst case scenary I would expect is <20ms (7.5ms sampling + max 10ms over-air-transfer delay).